# Use & in SQL Server UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a query like

```
UPDATE myTable SET Name='B&L' WHERE ID = 1;
```

The problem is I am getting the following error:

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'B'.

My column is of type `varChar` and as you can see I am escaping the string with 'quotes'. How can I get the & symbol to insert?

Thanks.

Comment: Running that update straight in SSMS would be fine. How are you submitting the query?

Comment: This is not a linked server query is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MSSQL try escaping the `&` by enclosing it in square brackets so it would become:

```
UPDATE myTable SET Name='B[&]L' WHERE ID = 1;
```

Or you could use the `ESCAPE` statment like so:

```
UPDATE myTable SET Name='B\&L' WHERE ID = 1 ESCAPE '\';
```

Comment: These are good options, but as it turns out when I was sending the data via ajax it was being corrupted. I switched the jquery ajax function and the query works as is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your statement should work in SQL Server.  I saw some instances of Oracle that had issues with ampersands.  In those cases, you could use something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET Name='B&' + 'L' WHERE ID = 1
```